# Differential Equation Multiple Choice

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples

[image] Hi all. This question is from a major paper here in Australia. Markers claim that the correct answer is B and simple separation and a few integrals certainly suggest that B is correct with a soln involving arctan.

BUT

Why is D not also a correct solution. It seems to satisfy the DE?? If I draw the direction field it seems that D can be produced.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. Why can't I just follow the direction fields to produce D?

Comment: Is it not true that D has a horizontal tangent at those points?